# How can I get input from undefined number of button Controller

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, nodemcu, numeric-keypad

If i want to get input from 20 to 30 buttons (Consider as a 30 Buttons of keypad), then what is the best approach to achieve it?
Is these any keyboard available in market or I need to make it with my own talent?

Better if you can suggest with reference to Nodemcu,Esp8266, V3.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are cheap keypads available in the market which can be used with Arduino. They can take 4-5 pins to attach and then, you cannot utilize the pins for other use. Thus, you can use `OnewireKeypad.h` library. With this, you'll just require only one pin for data transfer, unlike the previous traditional way. You can go [here](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/OneWireKeyPad/) for further info on how to do it.

The other way is to use an old PS2 PC keyboard which will take 4 wires and a library. Go [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Connect-Arduino-UNO-to-USB-Keyboard/) for further info about this.

These methods can all be implemented for NodeMCU, ESP8266, etc.

Comment: This is a nice technique using the adc. If I like to use it in "Lua Scripting" then I need to check ADC with a minimum interval of time(100ms). So, is it a good technique? or Is there ADC interrupt in "NodeMCU Lua scripting"? or else what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There are cheap fixed folio matrix keyboards with 16/20 keys per pad. You need 4-5 pins to attach, libraries can be found via library manager in ArduinIDE.

A [nice hack is the use of an old PS2 PC keyboard](https://www.instructables.com/id/Connect-PS2-Keyboard-to-Arduino/) which only needs four wires and a programm -see link for details.
You can easelyadapt for NodeMCU and if you get a cheap extra numeric keypad (normaly 30-32 keys) or a gamer extension board (up to appr. 50 keys) you can do all nice things you want